# Referencing Android Views from within a Java class

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, findviewbyid

I have a class that extends Activity and parses an xml file. The text I want from within the xml file is passed as arguments to a java class. The problem I have is that in the java class I want to reference android TextViews from the resource Layout folder so I can set the text to the String arguments I pass in. I guess I can extend the java class from Activity or pass in as an argument the current activity...are they the only to reference the files in res/layout?

```
public class xmlClass extends Activity{
    //parse the xml    
    MyDataFile mdf = new MyDataFile(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);     
}

public class MyDataFile{
    public MyDataFile(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
    {

    }    
    ******* Here I want to set the Text in a TextView to arg1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

first is, to make MyDataFile a Nested Class from your Activity like this:

```
public class xmlClass extends Activity{

    //keep TextViews as member
    protected TextView mTextView

    public void onCreate(){
        ...
        setContentView(...)
        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_id);

        //parse your XML
        MyDataFile mdf = new MyDataFile(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
    }

    //make MyDataFile a nested class
    public class MyDataFile{

        public MyDataFile(String arg1,String arg2, ...){
            mTextView.setText(arg1);
        }
    }
```

Second solution is to give the TextViews as parameters like in this Constructor

```
    public MyDataFile(String arg1, TextView textForArg1, ...){
        textForArg1.setText(arg1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `findViewById(R.id.myResId)` method to find your view after you have called the `setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);` method.

If you want to set your text to a `TextView` you can use `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.myResId)).setText(R.string.myText);` directly.

If you want to access your views from within a class that is not it's own `Context` you can pass a context in the method parameters and then call `context.findViewById(...)`.

But this is prone to result in Context-leaks sooner or later.
A better way to solve your problem is to have a getter for your text and set it from within the `Activity` or `Fragment` that hosts the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
yourTextView.setText(yourText);
```

Answer (score 0):

On your layout xml, find the textview and set:

```
android:id = "lorem"
```

Then on your activity class:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lorem);
```

and pass txt somehow to your data class. (passing as an argument is valid).

Then:

```
txt.setText(arg1);
```